# Dual pivot quick sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, java-8

I was analyzing the code for Arrays.sort() method in java . My question is for what values of integer array a[] will this code return true ?

```
     if (less < e1 && e5 < great)
```

After Sorting left and right parts recursively, excluding known pivots for what value of array a[] will the center part become too large (comprises > 4/7 of the array) ?

Given QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD = 286 .
Array size cannot be more than 286

Any example of int array please .

Answer (score 2):

It happens when all candidates for pivots are close to either the maximum or the minimum value of the array.

`java.util.DualPivotQuicksort#sort()` chooses the pivots from 5 positions in the array:

```
    int seventh = (length >> 3) + (length >> 6) + 1;
    int e3 = (left + right) >>> 1; // The midpoint
    int e2 = e3 - seventh;
    int e1 = e2 - seventh;
    int e4 = e3 + seventh;
    int e5 = e4 + seventh;
```

So, in order to construct an array that satisfies the condition, we need to fill those 5 positions with extreme values. For example:

```
int[] x = {
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2,  /* e1 = 10 */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1,              /* e2 = 17 */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,               /* e3 = 24 */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,               /* e4 = 31 */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,               /* e5 = 38 */
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};
Arrays.sort(x);
```

And a non-trivial case where the method changes the boundaries of the central part before sorting it:

```
int[] x = {
        70, 66, 11, 24, 10, 28, 58, 13, 19, 90, 15,
        79, 16, 69, 39, 14, 10, 16,
        40, 59, 47, 77, 90, 50, 50,
        50, 16, 76, 86, 70, 33, 90,
        24, 35, 73, 93, 87, 19, 91,
        73, 87, 22, 15, 24, 92, 34, 35, 98, 11, 40
};
```

Comment: The center part remains the same after sorting left and right parts recursively .for your array Unnecessary comparisons made when center part is too large . Any other example array please .

Comment: @RajGopalBhallamudi I added an example of an array where the additional partitioning step is not trivial, because the central part contains values equal to the chosen pivots (in this case 16 and 90).

Comment: Mind blowing example . Great effort . Moreover the code did not mention in it's comments that it also handles array with duplicate values . Thanks for the help .